# Long contenteditable div masked as input horizontal scrolling by mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, contenteditable

If input is too short for the whole text to be visible, user can use mouse dragging to horizontally scroll text inside input. Is there any way to achieve this behavior in contenteditable field masked as input?

```
<div contenteditable="true">...some long text...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your answer correctly, but this seems to be the default behavior when you apply `overflow:hidden` to the contenteditable element. With `white-space:nowrap` (and some css fiddling) you can create your own `<input>` elements (I recreated the ones from MacOS Safari):

```css
[contenteditable] {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 146px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden; /* here it is */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<label>Input: <input value="Lorem ipsum dolor amet slow-carb drinking vinegar actually green juice hell of literally locavore sriracha keytar health goth cold-pressed seitan bushwick quinoa. 8-bit iceland microdosing, prism hell of lyft cold-pressed cloud bread retro live-edge hammock. Tilde fanny pack street art green juice tote bag everyday carry. Kickstarter retro +1, mumblecore echo park next level heirloom adaptogen air plant locavore helvetica. Copper mug craft beer neutra, sriracha chartreuse shoreditch man bun ugh vice ethical authentic."></label>
<label>Contenteditable: <div contenteditable>Lorem ipsum dolor amet slow-carb drinking vinegar actually green juice hell of literally locavore sriracha keytar health goth cold-pressed seitan bushwick quinoa. 8-bit iceland microdosing, prism hell of lyft cold-pressed cloud bread retro live-edge hammock. Tilde fanny pack street art green juice tote bag everyday carry. Kickstarter retro +1, mumblecore echo park next level heirloom adaptogen air plant locavore helvetica. Copper mug craft beer neutra, sriracha chartreuse shoreditch man bun ugh vice ethical authentic.</div></label>
```

Comment: This does not work, I am still only able to scroll contenteditable with keyboard arrows but not with mouse.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/DmitriyKozyatinskiy/pen/rNBezgJ
My Chrome version: 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You're right. I tested only in Safari and there it works. But neither in Chrome nor Firefox. Seems like the only time where Safari works as expected whereas Chrome/Firefox do not...